# Google map android. Динамически высчитывать радиус в метрах

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Хотел бы узнать, как можно динамически рассчитывать радиус видимой карты в метрах. Получается только возвращать точки со статичным радиусом 20000 метров во круг своей точки.

```
{"center":[76.949916,43.228101], "radius": 2000}
```

Есть ли какой нибудь алгоритм, который высчитывает радиус в метрах? Если есть, пожалуйста напиши. Уже день ничего стоящее не могу найти. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Есть какой-то класс для этого специальный. Ну или получите координаты краёв экрана - вот и радиус без учёта кривизны планетв

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Динамически вычислять радиус, как озвучил @ЮрийСПб под моим вопрос. 
Сразу нашёл реализацию. Очень хорошая реализация. При приближении к карте значения меняются. Радиус высчитывается в метрах с очень не большой погрешностью(Можете не обращать внимание даже на неё).

```
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                    String TAG = "FEED MAP";
                    LatLngBounds bounds = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
                    LatLng target = cameraPosition.target;
                    LatLng northEast = bounds.northeast;
                    LatLng southEast = bounds.southwest;
                    float[] results1 = new float[1];
                    float[] results2 = new float[1];
                    Location.distanceBetween(target.latitude, target.longitude, northEast.latitude, northEast.longitude, results1);
                    Location.distanceBetween(target.latitude, target.longitude, southEast.latitude, southEast.longitude, results2);
                    double distance = results1[0] > results2[0] ? results1[0] : results2[0];
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCameraChange:" + results1[0] + "  " + results2[0]);
                }
            });
```

Вот сами логи:

```
FEED MAP: onCameraChange:2553.2026  2555.6477
FEED MAP: onCameraChange:1276.6926  1277.7365
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]